# ANTLR3 does not match extended ASCII characters

Tags: antlr, antlr3, antlrworks

I'm using ANTLRWorks to test a grammar I came up with and one of the rules foresees usage of BULLET symbol •, but when parse tree is being built it escapes it every time. I also tried other chars from extended ASCII table and they are omitted as well. Is it a know bug or should I enable extended ASCII chars somehow?

Answer (score 1):

ANTLR 3.x through 4.0 can match any UTF-16 code unit except U+FFFF. ANTLR 4.1 will be able to match U+FFFF as well. To match characters in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF, you'll need to explicitly encode them as UTF-16 surrogate pairs in your grammar.

Comment: Hey, bullet char, does it fall in the range U+10000 to U+10FFFF? It's unicode is "\u2022". If so, how could it be transformed into UTF-16 surrogate pair? Where can i look it up?

Comment: @IhorM. No, that character falls into the range of characters that ANTLR can handle without any special considerations. Just use `'\u2022'` in the lexer portion of your grammar.

Comment: This is exactly what i did initially. I tested it in ANTLRWorks. In input box i put "x•y" and in a Parse Tree i see NoViableAltException.

Comment: Were you using the interpreter or debugger mode of ANTLRWorks? The interpreter frequently gives incorrect results. Either way, this would be a bug in ANTLRWorks if anything, because support for characters like `\u2022` is well tested in ANTLR itself. You weren't specific about anything in your original post so you'll probably want to write up a detailed example to file an issue here: https://github.com/antlr/antlrworks/issues

Comment: Looks to me as a ANTLRWorks issue. Thx for sorting this out.

Comment: You are right, i tested it in Java code and everything works fine.